# Creating a check using multiple arguments to produce three different results

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I need to find the most succinct way to return one of three values based on two arguments. I think a switch statement is the most succinct but please suggest alternatives.

I have two arguments, `type` and `action`

If `action == 'close'` then the returned result should always be `'Hide'`

If `action == open` then more checks are needed

If `action == 'open' && type == 'flight'` return `show more flights`

If `action == 'open' && type == 'protection'` return `show protections`

What's the most succinct way to do this without involving multiple nested `if` statements? This whole statement is already inside another `if` statement called by a ternary so I don't really want to add more.

This is my current solution, any way I can make this lighter?

```
createShowLabels: function(testEnabled,action,type){
                if (testEnabled){
                    if(action === 'open'){
                        switch(type) {
                            case 'flight':
                                return 'Show flight times';
                            case 'protection':
                                return 'What\'s this?';
                        }
                    } else {
                        return 'Hide';
                    }
                } else {
                    // Defaults
                    if (action === 'open'){
                        return 'Show more';
                    } else {
                        return 'Show less';
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: And Whats you attempt?

Comment: Can one assume that `action` and `type` will **only** have the values listed above?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, `action` can only be `open/close` and `type` can only be `flight/protection`

Comment: You do not need the `break` after a `return` :)

Comment: I understand your concerns about nesting things, but an excellent solution is to write your code in a way that is very easy to understand its structure and hierarchy. You may find what I believe is a good example in my answer below. Be aware, however, that there is a lot of **taste** perspectives and hence there are no clear and universal rules. Just imagine that somebody else would need to read your code and you want to make his/her life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's be clear: "Succinct" is not a synonym for "good," "readable," or "maintainable." *Sometimes* succinct code is good, readable, and maintainable; sometimes, it isn't.

Given your guarantee in the comments that the values will **only** be the ones listed, there are several ways.

In my own code, I would probably use somnething like [FDavidov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39143803/157247) but with different formatting:

```
if (action == 'close') {
    result = 'Hide';
} else if (type == 'flight') {
    result = 'show more flights';
} else {
    result = 'show protections';
}
```

But you asked for the most succinct way. The conditional operator is succinct, but not necessarily hyper-easy to debug:

```
result = action == 'close' ? 'Hide' : type == 'flight' ? 'show more flights' : 'show protections';
```

Example:

```js
function test(action, type) {
  return action == 'close' ? 'Hide' : type == 'flight' ? 'show more flights' : 'show protections';
}
console.log(test('close', 'flight'));
console.log(test('close', 'protections'));
console.log(test('open', 'flight'));
console.log(test('open', 'protections'));
```

---

These are all less concise but more *configurable*:

You can use a lookup object:

```
var lookup = {
    'close|flight': 'Hide',
    'close|protections': 'Hide',
    'open|flight': 'show more flights',
    'open|protections': 'show protections'
};

result = lookup[action + '|' + type];
```

Example:

```js
var lookup = {
    'close|flight': 'Hide',
    'close|protections': 'Hide',
    'open|flight': 'show more flights',
    'open|protections': 'show protections'
};

function test(action, type) {
    return lookup[action + '|' + type];
}
console.log(test('close', 'flight'));
console.log(test('close', 'protections'));
console.log(test('open', 'flight'));
console.log(test('open', 'protections'));
```

Or as you say, a switch:

```
switch (action + '|' + type) {
    case 'close|flight':      result = 'Hide'; break;
    case 'close|protections': result = 'Hide'; break;
    case 'open|flight':       result = 'show more flights'; break;
    case 'open|protections':   result = 'show protections'; break;
};
```

Example:

```js
function test(action, type) {
    var result;
    switch (action + '|' + type) {
        case 'close|flight':      result = 'Hide'; break;
        case 'close|protections': result = 'Hide'; break;
        case 'open|flight':       result = 'show more flights'; break;
        case 'open|protections':   result = 'show protections'; break;
    };
    return result;
}
console.log(test('close', 'flight'));
console.log(test('close', 'protections'));
console.log(test('open', 'flight'));
console.log(test('open', 'protections'));
```

Comment: Do you think my above solution is better or worse? I don't want to add unnecessary complication because I'm trying to write less code. The above solution though feels very long-winded. Is there an in-between?

Comment: Thank you for providing several detailed examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for **short-handed** phrasing, this is not what you are looking for. This is a very simple and **READABLE** way to write what you want:

```
if (action == 'close') {
   return 'Hide';
}
else if (action = 'open') {
    if      (type = 'flight'    ) {return 'show more flights'}
    else if (type = 'protection') {return 'show protections' }
}
```